# ID from another table on insertion using PDO

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, insert

I am creating a quiz based system which part of it includes 2 tables:

Answer_bank table:

```
+-------+---------+----------+
| ab_id | ab_name | ab_qb_id |
+-------+---------+----------+
```

and a Question_bank table:

```
+-------+-------------+
| qb_id | qb_question | 
+-------+-------------+
```

The aim is to allow someone to create a question and an answer, the answer will be stored within the answer bank table with the `ab_qb_id` equal to the `qb_id`. I don't want this in the same table as I will be making this more complex.

I try to use the following PDO/SQL to insert into both the tables.

```
//questions
$qb_id = $_POST['qb_id'];
$qb_question = $_POST['qb_question'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO questions_bank (`qb_id`, `qb_question`)
        VALUES (:qb_id, :qtn)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(":qb_id", $qb_id);
$stmt->bindValue(":qtn", $qb_question);
$stmt->execute();

//answers
$ab_name = $_POST['ab_name'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO answers_bank (`ab_name`, `ab_qb_id`) VALUES (:ab_name, :qb_id)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':ab_name', $ab_name);
$stmt->bindValue(':qb_id', $qb_id);
$stmt->execute();
```

However the problem I have is the `ab_qb_id` in the `answer_bank` table always inserts `0` and not the same id as `qb_id`. Is this the incorrect way to do this? What's the best way for the answer table to include the `qb_id` ?... So that then the answer is related to a specific question. Thank you

Comment: are you using 2 different forms here?

Comment: Just one form, should I be using two? @Fred-ii-

Comment: hard to say really and as to what's being filled in or not. If one of those isn't being filled, then that's what I suspect is happening; it's left empty and that your column has a default value of 0. Make sure all form elements have their respective and matching name attributes.

Comment: Is there even a `$_POST['qb_id']` or is the resulting `$qb_id` simply empty and are you relying on the auto-increment value of the database? That's what it sounds like at least...

Comment: @Fred-ii- qb_id inserts into the questions_bank table and echo's on the pages fine. But it inserts 0 to the answers_bank table. Its just a standard int row.

Comment: use `isset()` or `!empty()` on all your POST arrays and see what comes of it.

Comment: @jeroen i've done some testing and it seems that case, the value on the hidden id form was empty. How would you be able to POST the id if it's automatically AI on insert?

Comment: Can you `describe Answer_bank;`? I think `qb_id` in `Question_bank` is the primary key so that's why it works for questions but `ab_qb_id` is just a regular column. So `->lastInsertId()` should work and you don't need to supply anything for `qb_id`.

Comment: See @Michael's answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would personally get the ID of the row that was just inserted in the `questions_bank` table and then use that ID as the value you insert into the `answers_bank.ab_qb_id` column. Because you're using PDO, you can use this: `$db->lastInsertId()`. For example:

```
$qb_id = $_POST['qb_id'];
$qb_question = $_POST['qb_question'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO questions_bank (`qb_id`, `qb_question`)
    VALUES (:qb_id, :qtn)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(":qb_id", $qb_id);
$stmt->bindValue(":qtn", $qb_question);
$stmt->execute();
$inserted_id = $db->lastInsertId();

//answers
$ab_name = $_POST['ab_name'];
$sql = "INSERT INTO answers_bank (`ab_name`, `ab_qb_id`) VALUES (:ab_name, :qb_id)";
$stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
$stmt->bindValue(':ab_name', $ab_name);
$stmt->bindValue(':qb_id', $inserted_id); //Use the previously inserted ID
$stmt->execute();
```

Using this method will ensure that the `questions_bank.qb_id` and `answers_bank.ab_qb_id` are the same. To make sure that any interruptions (power surge, disk failure, etc.) don't have a chance to affect this, you can wrap these in a transaction. Then you can be sure that the values will always match.

**EDIT** I forgot to add the `try{}catch{}` statement to the transaction:

For example:

```
try{
    $db->beginTransaction();
    //Your current queries
    $db->commit();
}catch(Exception $e){
    $db->rollback();
    die($e->getMessage());
}
```

Comment: You might want to add that this is probably happening because there is no `$_POST['qb_id']`; that's why a value gets inserted in the first query but not in the second. So only the question needs to get inserted in the firest query.

Comment: @jeroen which is basically what I told the OP earlier ;-)

Comment: @Fred-ii- I definitely didn't get that from your comment so that is why I added my own :-) But it is late...

Comment: @jeroen *"hard to say really and as to what's being filled in or not. If one of those isn't being filled, then that's what I suspect is happening"* ;-) which is what I meant. and *"Make sure all form elements have their respective and matching name attributes"*

Comment: @Fred-ii- It's been a long day :-)

Comment: @jeroen Double shot of espresso will take care of that ;-)

Comment: This is the best I can do from here as far as the double shot of espresso:   .C|__|

Comment: Thank you all you were all completely right. Also the `lastInsertId()` works perfectly, never knew that existed!

Comment: @StackMeUp123 Always a pleasure. However, from a comment you left up there *"the value on the hidden id form was empty"* - that could mean  that you didn't properly setup your query/loop to catch it. Having posted your HTML form, would have most likely revealed. that. Oh well, the important thing is that it's been resolved. ;-) But... `lastInsertId()` is the better method for sure.